# Webhooks have stopped working firebase stripe extensions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have been developing a web app for few months now and installed `stripe-firebase-extensions` to handle subscriptions and they worked flawlessly but for some reason the webhooks have stopped working today. If i try to send some test hooks then they are being sent and working but they have stopped working on their own. I have checked everything that i could but they are not working. Any help would be appreciated. As far as i can tell the problem might be from stripe's end not firebase

My webhooks:

[image: My webhooks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write into Support so you can share the details and they can investigate this for you: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: There was an issue from stripe it was fixed after 24 hours